# Pyhton - Optimizing Multithreaded Disk I/O

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, io

I am currently evaluating the reading and writing performance of the ASUS Hyper M.2 x16 Gen 4 card. For my tests, I am using a script to read and write 5,000 dummy files, each 11MB in size. Below is the code I'm using:

```
import os
import time
import logging
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import shutil

def write_file(file_path, size_mb):
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(os.urandom(size_mb * 1024 * 1024))

def read_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return data

def simulate_disk_io(base_path, num_files, size_mb, max_workers):
    # create a directory for the files if it doesn't exist.
    os.makedirs(base_path, exist_ok=True)
    start_time = time.time()
    logging.info(f"TIME: {datetime.datetime.now()}, WRITING FILES STARTED")
 
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        for i in range(num_files):
            file_path = os.path.join(base_path, f"file_{i}.dat")
            executor.submit(write_file, file_path, size_mb)

    write_duration = time.time() - start_time
    logging.info(f"Writing {num_files} files took {write_duration} seconds.")

    start_time = time.time()
    logging.info(f"TIME: {datetime.datetime.now()}, READING FILES STARTED")
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        for i in range(num_files):
            file_path = os.path.join(base_path, f"file_{i}.dat")
            executor.submit(read_file, file_path)

    read_duration = time.time() - start_time
    logging.info(f"Reading {num_files} files took {read_duration} seconds.")

    total_mb = num_files * size_mb  # Total MB processed
    logging.info(f"Write Throughput: {total_mb / write_duration} MB/s")
    logging.info(f"Read Throughput: {total_mb / read_duration} MB/s")
    
    shutil.rmtree(base_path)
    logging.info(f"TIME: {datetime.datetime.now()},Cleanup completed.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
logging.basicConfig('read_write_test.log', level=logging.INFO)
simulate_disk_io(r"F:\disk_test", 5000, 11, 30)
```

I am achieving approximately 500MB/s write speed and 1000MB/s read speed. These results are similar to the random file read/write results I observed when testing the disk with CrystalDiskMark. I suspect that the randomness in read and write performance is due to the use of multithreading.

Is there a way to optimize my code so that some parts are read and written sequentially to potentially improve performance?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: `os.urandom` might be a bottleneck : generating random numbers is generally pretty slow AFAIK (dependent of the target OS). `f.read()` may be sub-optimal : I expect it to do memory copies internally (certainly multiple ones due to the libc stack too). I am not sure Python can compete with a low-level native benchmark but it should certainly not be so far for this use-case.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, thank you for your comment. I replaced os.urandom with np.zeros(). The writing time did not change significantly; it remains around 500 MB. However, I think you are correct about the bottleneck. The f.read() results are quite satisfying, as it achieves speeds over 3000 MB/s most of the time. In some test trials, the reading speed decreases to around 1000 MB/s, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: Ha, I know : this is certainly due to the SLC cache. You are writing a huge amount of data (55 GiB) so the SLC cache might not be big enough to contain all the written data (not the part read). Vendors report SLC cache usage (for obvious marketing reasons). If you want to compare your code with CrystalDiskMark, then you need to read/write the same quantity in the benchmarking application. Throttling due to heating also matter (but for both your application and the benchmark).

Comment: Note that `np.zero` will not be very fast the first time data is touched (read or written) due to page faults. This is a problem especially on Windows since it might do page faults for reads/writes already. The thoughput of page faults is generally few GiB/s though so it should not explain the write speed (but it may have a non-negligible impact on the read speed).

Comment: If you want not to have any page-fault or RAM write overhead, then you need to pre-allocate an array with `np.full` and reuse it many times. I expect this effect to be small compared to the SLC cache which is certainly the bottleneck.

Comment: If you want to read/write huge amount of data without a decreasing speed beyond a given amount of data (typically dozens of GiB), then you need to use a SLC professional SSD which are much more expensive. MLC are relatively fast so they can be a good tread-off. TLC/QLC SSD are clearly not made for that. Here, I cannot find relevant information about the SLC cache on your disk (nor even any useful advanced technical details)... It seems the card can contains multiple SSDs. Can you please report which type of SSD (cells) is contained inside?

Comment: @JérômeRichard, thanks a lot! I was not aware of SLC cache, have a look at it. Yeah, the card contains 4 Samsung Pro 2Tb.  SLC Write Cache: approx. 236 GB (230 GB Dynamic + 6 GB Static). I don't know if dynamic or statitc applies in my case. Static?

Comment: "Samsung Pro" is a group of SSD but not one specific SSD (e.g. mine is the Samsung 980 Pro 1 TiB PCIE 4). Do you have the exact reference/name? I think the static part applies here. I expect the dynamic part to be MLC/TLC/QLC cells reserved for the cache (dependent of the exact disk -- and I'm not sure about this). I guess 236 GiB of SLC cells would be quite a lot (though 6 GiB of SLC cells seems rather small).

Comment: I think you can get the size of the SLC cache by writing a big chunk of data and reading it back multiple times, with an increasing size. You should see a jump when data cannot fit in cache. The downside of this solution is that it reduce the lifespan of the disk since the cells have a fixed number of writes and it is already quite low for the TLC/QLC (hence the SLC cache to mitigate this issue). You can do some tests with CrystalDiskMark for example.

Comment: Ok, I see, I don't know exact type of the SSD right now, but I wll check it. Btw, we are doing lots of write and read tests, then we should be more careful about lifespan of the disks. I will check this as well.

Comment: WD_BLACK SN770 NVMe™-SSD -- This article has a nice graph, shows what you already explained. : https://www.techpowerup.com/review/wd-black-sn770-1-tb/6.html

Comment: Yeah. Indeed. This explains how the dynamic caching works on this SSD. The TLC cells that can usually store 3 bits, actually store 1 bit. The SLC cache size is an optimistic limit : 325 is the maximum because nearly all TLC cells are used in SLC mode. In practice, some TLC cells cannot be used in SLC mode because they actually store useful data. So if you have stored like 700 GiB of data, then the SLC cache should be about 100 GiB (maximum). Besides, the SLC cache takes some time to free and flash blocks may prevent some cells to be used in SLC mode, so you may see a smaller cache in practice.